# Oracle Database Security - Insert specific values only

Tags: oracle, security, oracle11g, insert, roles

I'm starting to explore some capabilities of Oracle Database Security (11G), and I have created a small fictitious banking database. One of the tables is "TRANSACTIONS" with columns such as:

- TRANS_ID
- DATE
- DESCRIPTION
- TYPE
  etc.

I'm going to be creating users such as Customers and Bank Tellers, but I want to limit what they can do. The question I have is: Can I allow a user to insert data into the TRANSACTIONS table, but only if it's of a specific type, or has a specific description?

For instance, I want my Bank Teller user to be able to insert a "FEE REVERSAL" and a Withdrawal or Deposit only. Is this as simple as creating a role such as:

```
CREATE ROLE TELLER_ROLE IDENTIFIED BY TELLER;
GRANT UPDATE ON TRANSACTIONS TO TELLER_ROLE
WHERE TRANSACTION.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'FEE REVERSAL';
```

Or should I go about this a different way?

Comment: If you want that level of granular control you would be better off to only let users insert/delete/update through a stored procedure where you can allow or disallow to a fine degree

Answer (score 0):

Assigning ROLES to users is very important to limit what they can do within the database but I feel you are looking more for data constraints to be enforced. Depending on what you are using for a front-end you can limit their options or even utilize stored procedures to only pass certain values but to enforce the data integrity at the database level you will want to use CONSTRAINTS. Example below;

```
ALTER TABLE transactions
ADD CONSTRAINT check_teller_transaction
  CHECK (record_action IN ('FEE REVERSAL', 'WITHDRAWAL', 'DEPOSIT'));
```